# Large string resources slowing down my app

Tags: java, android, resources, storing-data

I have book app where I store text in string resources. I have to access them dinamically like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String ID = intent.getStringExtra("ID");
String titleText = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("t"+ID, "string", getPackageName()));
String contentText = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("c"+ID, "string", getPackageName()));
```

Chapters in my app loads very slow. I tryed to store each chapter in separate resource file. That didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: How large is "large"?

Comment: Start by using method tracing, or even just `Log` statements, to determine the exact lines of code that are taking up the time.

Comment: Around 500K characters total

Comment: And around 3-5K chars each chapter

Comment: you should have your data in xml. this way, your string translation won't be a problem and you will have all you string references at one place. (no need to call getIdentifier)

Comment: @RahulKumar I store my string resources in xml. I don't need to translate anything. I just want to store data anywhere.

Comment: you can save your data in json format in assets folder then. make a model class and access your data from there. it would be clean and elegant.